# Clojure koans: (if false []) vs (if false [:a :b :c])

Tags: clojure

I've started learning Clojure this week. I'm working my way through the conditional koans and don't understand the following assertions:

```
  "Some of them leave you no alternative"
  (= [] (if (> 4 3)
      []))

  "And in such a situation you may have nothing"
  (= nil (if (nil? 0)
      [:a :b :c]))
```

The second one does what I would expect -- the condition evaluates to false-- [EDIT: Actually, it's true and I'm just still not used to 'operator-first' reasoning!], `if` tries to return the second alternative, finds none, and so returns `nil`. So, why doesn't the first return `nil`? Is it because an empty structure is 'close enough' to nil?

Comment: Because 4 is greater than 3 and your question title suggest that you thought `(> 4 3)` to be false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the first `if` evaluates to true (as 4 is indeed greater than 3), so else-clause is irrelevant. It returns the then-clause, which is defined and equal to `[]`.